# Using asp.net, how do I get the status of a WebRequest object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mstest

I am writing some tests to ensure I am receiving a 200 status, even if no data is present. I am able to connect to the backend with my testing, but don't know how to read the data and then use the data in an Assert statement to confirm the status code is 200.

```
    public void DataControllerTest_NoData(long dataId)
  {
        var uri = "http://localhost:8311/api/Data?columnId=";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri + dataId);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        try
      {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
      }
       catch (WebException we)
      {
       statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
      }

      Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, statusCode);
      response.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`. Later provides access to the [StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say you don't know how to get the status code...then you say you're getting a 500 status code. Which is it?

Comment: @BenTen You have updated your post  so many times that now it does not contain any question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to find the status code if you see an error by adjusting your code with a small correction as shown below.

```
public void DataControllerTest_NoData(long dataId)
{
     var uri = "http://localhost:8311/api/Data?columnId=";
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri + dataId);
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
     request.Method = "GET";
     

     try
     {
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
         response.Close();
     }
     catch (WebException we)
     {
         statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
     }
     Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, statusCode);
}
```

If you want to find the code of the exception text, use the following code

```
try
{
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
   response.Close();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
   string resultError = we.Message;
}
```